# JS MediaRecorder API exports a non seekable WebM file

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, web-mediarecorder

I am working on a video editor, and the video is rendered using the canvas, so I use the JS MediaRecorder API, but I have run into an odd problem, where, because the MediaRecorder API is primarily designed for live streams, my exported WebM file doesn't show how long it is until it's done, which is kinda annoying.

This is the code I am using:

```js
function exportVideo() {
    const stream = preview.captureStream();
    const dest = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
    const sources = []
        .concat(...layers.map((layer) => layer.addAudioTracksTo(dest)))
        .filter((source) => source);
    // exporting doesn't work if there's no audio and it adds the tracks
    if (sources.length) {
        dest.stream.getAudioTracks().forEach((track) => stream.addTrack(track));
    }
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: usingExportType,
        videoBitsPerSecond: exportBitrate * 1000000,
    });

    let download = true;
    recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (e) => {
        const newVideo = document.createElement("video");
        exportedURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
        if (download) {
            const saveLink = document.createElement("a");
            saveLink.href = exportedURL;
            saveLink.download = "video-export.webm";
            document.body.appendChild(saveLink);
            saveLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(saveLink);
        }
    });

    previewTimeAt(0, false);

    return new Promise((res) => {
        recorder.start();
        audioContext.resume().then(() => play(res));
    }).then((successful) => {
        download = successful;
        recorder.stop();
        sources.forEach((source) => {
            source.disconnect(dest);
        });
    });
}
```

And if this is too vague, please tell me what is vague about it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Narrowed down the problem, this is a chrome bug, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012. I discovered a library called https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml that may be able to make the webm seekable, but unfortunately, this is a javascript project, and I ain't setting up Typescript.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this depends on the browser implementation.

Comment: Your code makes very little sense: Why do you go through the AudioContext here? Why do you even re-record what seems to be an already encoded media file? Also, how do you want to have a duration for a stream, that is being recorded? Do you want an API that is able to predict the future?

Comment: @Kaiido This is a video editor, so there is some audio tracks that also have to be recorded, otherwise the exported video would be silence.

Comment: Just add them directly to the mediastream you are capturing, no need to start an AudioContext just for that.

Answer (score 1):

> JS MediaRecorder API exports a non seekable WebM file

Yes, it does. It's in the nature of streaming.

In order to make that sort of stream seekable you need to post process it.  There's a [npm embl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebml) library pre-typescript if you want to attempt it.